# Files.readAllLine() not working after FileWriting

Tags: java, filewriter, file.readalllines

hoping you're doing well, this is my first question 
I have a trouble: 
My goal is to create java files from pieces of code (fields, attributes, constructor)
I tried to do this by altering between reading and writing file. 
***Reading file*** to get the old value , delete closing "}" 
***Writing in file*** :  the new piece of code, plus closing "}" 
The problem with my try is that Files.readAllLine() or FileWriter() is not working. 
You can find my source code below.

```
public static void fillFile(String fileName, String name, String value) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        List<String> all = Files.readAllLines(path,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(" the path "+Paths.get(fileName));
        System.out.println(name + " :; "+ value);
        System.out.println("to write " + all.toString().replaceAll(", ", " ").substring(1, (all+"").replaceAll(", ", " ").length()-1)  + "\n" +  name + (name.endsWith(")")?"":" = ")+ value+ (name.endsWith(")")?"":";")+"\n } ddddddddddddddddddddddd");
        FileWriter test = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
        test.write(all.toString().replaceAll(", ", " ").substring(1, all.toString().replaceAll(", ", " ").length()-1) +  "\n" +  name + (name.endsWith(")")?"":" = ")+ value+ (name.endsWith(")")?"":";")+"\n }");
        //test.flush();
        test.close();
    }
```

**Another question** : there is an other easy way to reach my goal ?

Comment: It would help to know exactly what is not working.

Comment: Post the content of the file you are reading.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I printed `all.size()` and it returns 0

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I generate the file (see my code above line 7)

Comment: *but I printed all.size() and it returns 0*  - and what does this mean?

Comment: What does `fileName` contain? Are you sure it is not a relative path and you confuse the working directory?

Comment: @ScaryWombat after the documentation of readAllLines(), it returns List<String> so if the size() is 0, I guess that the method is not returning anything

Comment: @MaartenBodewes good question, the `fileName` is a relative path, does this causes any problem ?

Comment: Depends in the end if the file referenced is correct and readable. Why not print out the absolute path using `toAbsolutePath`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes in fact, I am working in my team on "github" project, so that's wly I was prefering to work with relative path, I will try to see with absolute path, thank you

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It stills always not working

Comment: The problem is that the cause of this is outside our ability to debug given the code. If you have a UTF-8 text file then `readAllLines` should work.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I am actually using UTF-8 character, after looking in may pages in google, I found an example when they are using temporary files, I will try it. I thing it should fix the problem

Comment: Two hints: try and do less in your code, and certainly per line. Create methods. And don't rely on `toString` for any collection. Simply iterate over the lines instead.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes still not woking, filewriter causes problem

Comment: So `all` is filled now? "causes problem" is not a problem description.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes not yet
What makes me surprised is that the Files.readAllLines() is working when I put it just after closing the filewriter , but when exiting the method and reentering again, it doesn't work

Comment: Are you maybe writing a file that is in your class path or similar? Automatic rebuilding can remove those files again. You should not be updating *your own* source code that way. Code generation is frowned upon anyway.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes please explain me more, because I am using the automatic rebuild option (in eclipse)

Comment: Wish I could, out of time. Try again with source file in other folder in your file system. Check if that works first.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thank you for the help, I found the solution, I will put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that the `FileWriter` classe should have a different path that the one which `File.readAllLine()`use. 
So we have to create a temporary file, which will be copied to the desired `fileName` file, then we delete the temporary file 
Hope this will help people who need it. It is working !!!

```
public static void fillFile(String fileName, String name, String value) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        List<String> all = null;
        if (path.toFile().exists()) { 
            all = Files.readAllLines(path,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);}
        if(all!= null) System.out.println(path + " the size of "+ all.toArray(new String[all.size()])+"");
        Path path2 = Files.createTempFile(path.getParent(),"test-file", ".java");
        Files.write(path2, ((all+"").replaceAll(", ", "\n").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").substring(1, ((all+"").replaceAll(", ", " ").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "")).length()-1) +  "\n" +  name + value+ "\n" +"}").getBytes());
        Files.copy(path2, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Files.deleteIfExists(path2);
    }
```

Comment: Meh, that's only half of the story, your *original* code runs fine on a local file for reading & writing. Although it's so convoluted that it is tricky to spot what it exactly is trying to do.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yeah I think you're right, but for me it was enough, because as I told you I am working with relative path, on a local repository, and I am working with people who are using Linux, and I use windows.
It is important to make my code working on different OS
Anyway **thank you a lot**